# change made via felix console takes more precedence over apps and libs why?

Tags: aem, apache-felix

Scenario: The same configuration parameter is present under /libs/*/config and /apps/*/config and modified in both locations as well as via Felix console.

And during run-time somehow Felix console configuration is taking precedence. How? My understanding is /apps should take precedence. Any views.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct.  See
http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/current/deploying/configuring_osgi.html#Configuration%20Details which states:

> The following order of precedence is used:
>
> 1. Repository nodes under /apps/*/config....either with type sling:OsgiConfig or property files (CHECK)
> 2. Repository nodes with type sling:OsgiConfig under /libs/*/config.... (ootb defns)
> 3. Any .config files from /crx-quickstart/launchpad/config/.... on the local file system.
>
> This means that a generic configuration in /libs can be masked by a
> project specific configuration in /apps.

Are the config nodes [run-mode specific](http://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/kb/RunModeDependentConfigAndInstall.html)?  If a run-mode doesn't match, that could explain why the node under apps is not getting applied:

> As the same configuration parameter can be located in several places,
> the system:
>
> - searches for all nodes of type sling:OsgiConfig
> - filters according to service name
> - filters according to run mode

Also mentioned in the above doc, in case the changes were made when the system is running, then the following order of precedence applies:

> - Modifying a configuration in the Web console will take immediate effect as it takes precedence at runtime.
> - Modifying a configuration in /apps will take immediate effect.
> - Modifying a configuration in /libs will take immediate effect, unless it is masked by a configuration in /apps.

This might explain why the config changes done in the OSGI console is being picked instead of the changes in your /apps.

Comment: thanks for clarification but still not sure what might be the reason for this :(. As asked, `configuration` is not run-mode specific

Comment: learned one more thing, `felix > apps > libs` is precedence order while looking for configurations at *run time* and `apps > libs > felix` is the order while *startup*

Answer (score 0):

> The following order of precedence is used:
>
> ```
>     Repository nodes under /apps/*/config....either with type sling:OsgiConfig or property files (CHECK)
>     Repository nodes with type sling:OsgiConfig under /libs/*/config.... (ootb defns)
>     Any .config files from /crx-quickstart/launchpad/config/.... on the local file system.
>
> This means that a generic configuration in /libs can be masked by a project specific configuration in /apps.
> ```

In CQ5. Any changes done in felix console modifies the config files with the highest priority.

For eg under

> /apps/*/config you have an "org.apache.sling.security.impl.ReferrerFilter.config" file

**And you modify the Apache Sling Referrer Filter via felix console**

> The config file "org.apache.sling.security.impl.ReferrerFilter.config" present under /apps/*/config will be modified with the value you just entered in felix console.

Answer (score 0):

**Resolution order at Runtime**

Configuration changes made while the system is running trigger a reload with the modified configuration.

Then the following order of precedence applies:

1. Modifying a configuration in the **Web Console** will take immediate effect as it takes precedence at runtime.
2. Modifying a configuration in **/apps** will make immediate effect.
3. Modifying a configuration in **/libs** will take immediate effect, unless it is masked by a configuration in **/apps**.

**Resolution order at startup**

1. Repository nodes under **/apps/*/config**….. either with type sling:OsgiConfig or property files
2. Repository nodes with type sling:OsgiConfig under **/libs/*/config**…. (ootb)
3. Any **.config** files from **/crx-quickstart/launchpad/config/**… on the local file system